# Multiple http_access logic at the same time for squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to manage squid users to access the proxy if they logged in and the site url is allowed in my url list. They are running one by one. If logged in accesses but not check the url and vice versa. But I want both of them. Here is my config part. How can I do this?

```
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sqauth.php
auth_param basic children 20
auth_param basic realm Username and password
auth_param basic credentialsttl 5 hours

acl AuthenticatedUsers proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl allowed_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/allowedsites.txt"
acl all_others dst 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

http_access allow allowed_sites
http_access deny all_others
http_access allow AuthenticatedUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

I can find a and/or method to combine access control lines. So we can implement AND logic writing access control commands in the same line with gap.

**And logic**;

```
http_access allow accesses_to_google.com accesses_from_back_office
```

**OR logic**;

```
http_access allow accesses_to_google.com
http_access allow accesses_from_back_office
```

Here is the resource: https://workaround.org/squid-acls/